# How to make <flex-flow: column wrap>'s item shrink width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have this code: https://codepen.io/MH-123/pen/wvZJPPZ?editors=0100
As the screen width gets smaller, I want the left 2 boxes, 1 and 2 to shrink its width but I'm not sure how to achieve that as I'm new to flexbox. `flex-shrink 1` on them doesn't work. I'm not sure if my initial set up is incorrect at all? Is there a way I can just adjust this quickly?
Thanks!

```css
/* BASE STYLES */
:root {
  --clr-dark: #0f172a;
  --clr-light: #f1f5f9;
  --clr-accent: #e11d48;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1.6;
  word-spacing: 1.4px;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  color: var(--clr-dark);
  background-color: var(--clr-light);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 650px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 10px solid var(--clr-dark);
}

.item {
  background-color: #fb7185;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

/* END OF BASE STYLES */
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: space-around;
}

.item-1 {
  height: 30%;
  width: 50%;
  
  display: flex;
}

.item-a {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}

.item-b {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}

.item-2 {
  height: 55%;
  width: 50%;
}
.item-3 {
  height: 55%;
  width: 45%;
}
.item-4 {
  height: 30%;
  width: 45%;
}

@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    padding: 5% 1% 2% 1%;
  }
  .item-1 {
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column
  }
  .item-a, .item-b {
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .item-2 {
    height: 35%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .item-3 {
    height: 30%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .item-4 {
    height: 7.5%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media all and (max-height: 650px) {
  .container {
    background-color: pink;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    padding: 5% 1% 2% 1%;
  }
  .item-1 {
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column
  }
  .item-a, .item-b {
    height: 80%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .item-2 {
    height: 35%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .item-3 {
    height: 30%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .item-4 {
    height: 7.5%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item-1">
    <div class="item item-a">
      1b
    </div>
    <div class="item item-b">1a</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item item-2">2</div>
  <div class="item item-3">3</div>
  <div class="item item-4">
    4
  </div>
</div>
```